# Не могу зайти в PHPMYADMIN Docker-compose

Tags: php, nginx, phpmyadmin, docker, docker-compose

При переходе на localhost:8080, на страничку PHPMyadmin появляется 3 поля, сервер, логин, пароль.
Я записываю так:

```
server: mysql
login: root
password: secret
```

и мне выдает ошибки:

> 1. Невозможно подключиться к серверу MySQL
> 2. The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]
>
> 3.mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2054): The server requested  authentication method unknown to the client

Вот docker-compose.yml:

```
# Версия docker-compose
version: '3'
# Список наших сервисов (контейнеров)
services:
    nginx:
      # используем последний стабильный образ nginx
        image: nginx:latest
        # маршрутизируем порты
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        # монтируем директории, слева директории на основной машине, справа - куда они монтируются в контейнере
        volumes:
            - ./hosts:/etc/nginx/conf.d
            - ./www:/var/www
            - ./logs:/var/log/nginx
        # nginx должен общаться с php контейнером
        links:
            - php
    php:
        # у нас свой образ для PHP, указываем путь к нему и говорим что его надо собрать
        build: ./images/php
        # этот образ будет общаться с mysql
        links:
            - mysql
        # монтируем директорию с проектами
        volumes:
            - ./www:/var/www
    mysql:
        image: mysql:8
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        volumes:
            - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        container_name: phpmyadmin
        depends_on:
            - mysql
        environment:
            - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8080:80
        volumes:
            - /sessions
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если не ошибаюсь в mysql8, возможность аутентификации по паролю отключена по умолчанию. Решение или даунгрейд до 5 или подключить плагин аутентификации. 

Вот это должно помочь.

```
mysql:
    image: mysql:8
    command: ['--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password']
```